# Next.js Catch all folder and dynamic routing

Tags: routes, next.js, strapi

I have a Next.js 13 application using the pages structure which requires a region prefix, regions are fed from an API (strapi) and thus can't be set akin to how locales are set and as such i need to avoid duplicating my pages structure as it contains many nested pages. In the instances where a region isn't passed then i need it to default to an assigned default region e.g.

```
/[region]/[brand]/[location].js
/[region]/[brand]/[location].js
/[brand]/[location].js
```

Effectively following an appraoch like Apple.

https://www.apple.com/fr/store
https://www.apple.com/store

I have looked into the https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing and this seems to be based on a fixed at build time, which isn't possible.

Do i have to refactor and go down the optional catchall page route and have a very complex single [[...slug]].js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi likely yes. And the problem is that you can’t pass any additional info but slug from getStaticPaths